# malloc error in Linux, the same code on Mac OS X runs well

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, macos, posix

When I run my code in Mac OS X, it runs fine. However on Linux (Ubuntu), I get the following output:

```
pmichna@pawel-mac:~/alchemists$ ./alchemists 10
Creating 10 alchemists...
TESTING_ERROR #0
alchemists: malloc.c:2369: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
make: *** [run] Aborted (core dumped)
```

What's wrong?
My code:

```
pmichna@pawel-mac:~/alchemists$ cat alchemists.c

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_APPRENTICES 2

pthread_mutex_t *ingredients_mut;
pthread_mutex_t *pots_mut;
pthread_cond_t *ingredients_cond;
pthread_cond_t *pots_cond;
int *ingredients_count;
long num_of_pots;
long num_of_alchemists;
int *pots_usage;
// if the pot was used by the alchemist on the right: 1
// if on the left: -1
// if not yet used: 0

void lock_ingredients(long ingredients_index, long tid)
{
    printf("Alchemist #%ld trying to lock ingredients from bowl #%ld...\n", tid, ingredients_index);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&ingredients_mut[ingredients_index]);
    if(ingredients_count[ingredients_index]>1)
    {
        ingredients_count[ingredients_index]--;
        printf("Alchemist #%ld took an ingredient from bowl #%ld!\n", tid, ingredients_index);
    }
    else {
        printf("Alchemist #%ld found the bowl #%ld empty. Waiting for the filling apprentice...\n", tid, ingredients_index);
        pthread_cond_wait(&ingredients_cond[ingredients_index], &ingredients_mut[ingredients_index]);
    }
}

void lock_pot(long pot_index, long tid, int expected_pot_value)
{
    printf("Alchemist #%ld trying to lock pot #%ld...\n", tid, pot_index);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&pots_mut[pot_index]);
    if(pots_usage[pot_index] == 0 || pots_usage[pot_index] == expected_pot_value)
    {
        pots_usage[pot_index] = expected_pot_value;
        printf("Alchemist #%ld locked pot #%ld!\n", tid, pot_index);
    } else {
        printf("Alchemist #%ld found the pot #%ld dirty. :(\n", tid, pot_index);
        pthread_cond_wait(&pots_cond[pot_index], &pots_mut[pot_index]);
        printf("Alchemist #%ld now can use the cleaned pot #%ld!\n", tid, pot_index);
    }
}

void finish_production(int *gold_produced, long tid, long ingredients_index, long pot_index)
{
    (*gold_produced)++;
    printf("Alchemist #%ld produced gold!. Current status: %d\n", tid, *gold_produced);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ingredients_mut[ingredients_index]);
    printf("Alchemist #%ld released the bowl #%ld.\n", tid, ingredients_index);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pots_mut[pot_index]);
    printf("Alchemist #%ld released the pot #%ld.\n", tid, pot_index);
}


void alchemist_even_work(long tid, int *gold_produced) // has pot on the left; bowl on the right
{
    long pot_index = tid/2 - 1;
    long ingredients_index = tid/2;
    int expected_pot_value = 1;

    lock_ingredients(ingredients_index, tid);
    lock_pot(pot_index, tid, expected_pot_value);
    finish_production(gold_produced, tid, ingredients_index, pot_index);
}

void alchemist_odd_work(long tid, int *gold_produced) //has pot on the right; bowl on the left
{
    long pot_index = tid/2;
    long ingredients_index = tid/2;
    int expected_pot_value = -1;

    lock_ingredients(ingredients_index, tid);
    lock_pot(pot_index, tid, expected_pot_value);
    finish_production(gold_produced, tid, ingredients_index, pot_index);
}

void alchemist_first_work(long tid, int *gold_produced) // has pot on the left; bowl on the right
{
    long pot_index = num_of_alchemists/2 - 1;
    long ingredients_index = 0;
    int expected_pot_value = 1;

    lock_ingredients(ingredients_index, tid);
    lock_pot(pot_index, tid, expected_pot_value);
    finish_production(gold_produced, tid, ingredients_index, pot_index);
}

void *alchemist_work(void *id)
{
    long tid = (long)id;
    int sleep_time, gold_produced = 0;
    printf("Alchemist #%ld started\n", tid);

    while(gold_produced < 10)
    {
        //thinking
        srand((int)tid);
        sleep_time = rand()%5+1;
        printf("Alchemist #%ld going to think %d seconds...\n", tid, sleep_time);
        sleep(sleep_time);
        printf("Alchemist #%ld is going to try to make gold!\n", tid);

        if(tid == 0)
        {
            alchemist_first_work(tid, &gold_produced);
        } else if(tid%2 == 0)
        {
            alchemist_even_work(tid, &gold_produced);
        } else {
            alchemist_odd_work(tid, &gold_produced);
        }
    }
    printf("Alchemist #%ld going to lunch.\n", tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *apprentice_work(void *id)
{
    long tid = (long)id;
    long i;
    int sleep_time;
    switch (tid) {
        case 0:
            printf("Cleaning apprentice started.\n");
            break;

        case 1:
            printf("Ingredients apprentice started.\n");
            break;
    }
    srand((int)tid);

    while (1)
    {
        sleep_time = rand()%5+1;
        switch (tid) {
            case 0: // cleaner of pots
                printf("Cleaning apprentice going to sleep %d seconds...\n", sleep_time);
                sleep(sleep_time);
                printf("Cleaning apprentice is now going to clean all the pots\n");
                for(i = 0; i < num_of_pots; i++)
                {
                    pthread_mutex_lock(&pots_mut[i]);
                    printf("Apprentice cleaning pot #%ld\n", i);
                    pots_usage[i] = 0;
                    pthread_cond_signal(&pots_cond[i]);
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pots_mut[i]);
                }
                break;

            case 1: // ingredients
                printf("Ingredients apprentice going to sleep %d seconds...\n", sleep_time);
                sleep(sleep_time);
                printf("Ingredients apprentice going to fill all the pots...\n");
                for(i = 0; i < num_of_pots; i++)
                {
                    pthread_mutex_lock(&ingredients_mut[i]);
                    printf("Apprentice filling bowl #%ld\n", i);
                    ingredients_count[i] = 5;
                    pthread_cond_broadcast(&ingredients_cond[i]);
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ingredients_mut[i]);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long i;
    num_of_alchemists = atol(argv[1]);;
    if(num_of_alchemists%2 == 1)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Only even number of alchemists possible!\n");
            exit(1);
    }
    num_of_pots = num_of_alchemists/2; // this variable used alse as number of bowls with ingredients
    pthread_t threads_alchemists[num_of_alchemists];
    pthread_t threads_apprentices[NUM_APPRENTICES];
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    ingredients_mut = malloc(num_of_pots*sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
    pots_mut = malloc(num_of_pots*sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
    ingredients_cond = malloc(num_of_pots*sizeof(pthread_cond_t));
    ingredients_count = malloc(num_of_pots*sizeof(int));
    pots_usage = malloc(num_of_pots*sizeof(int));
    pots_cond = malloc(num_of_pots*sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));

    for(i = 0; i < num_of_pots; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_init(&ingredients_mut[i], NULL);
        pthread_mutex_init(&pots_mut[i], NULL);
        pthread_cond_init(&ingredients_cond[i], NULL);
        pthread_cond_init(&pots_cond[i], NULL);
        ingredients_count[i] = 5;
        pots_usage[i] = 0;
    }

    /* For portability, explicitly create threads in a joinable state */
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    printf("Creating %ld alchemists...\n", num_of_alchemists);
    for(i = 0; i < num_of_alchemists; i++)
    {
    printf("TESTING_ERROR #%ld\n", i);
        pthread_create(&threads_alchemists[i], &attr, alchemist_work, (void *)i);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_APPRENTICES; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&threads_apprentices[i], &attr, apprentice_work, (void *)i);
    }

    /* Wait for all threads to complete */
    for (i = 0; i < num_of_alchemists; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads_alchemists[i], NULL);
    }
    printf ("Main(): Waited and joined with %ld alchemist threads.\n", num_of_alchemists);

    // Clean up
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    for(i = 0; i < num_of_pots; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&ingredients_mut[i]);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&pots_mut[i]);
        pthread_cond_destroy(&ingredients_cond[i]);
        pthread_cond_destroy(&pots_cond[i]);
    }
    free(ingredients_mut);
    free(ingredients_count);
    free(ingredients_cond);
    free(pots_mut);
    free(pots_usage);
    free(pots_cond);
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

So used valgrind and the program runs, spitting out errors from time to time. What I noticed, they mostly concern conditional variables. One example which appeared just at the beginning:

```
pmichna@pawel-mac:~/alchemists$ valgrind --tool=memcheck ./alchemists 4
==3552== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3552== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3552== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3552== Command: ./alchemists 4
==3552== 
==3552== Invalid write of size 4
==3552==    at 0x4E3FA32: pthread_cond_init@@GLIBC_2.3.2 (pthread_cond_init.c:33)
==3552==    by 0x4018AA: main (in /home/pmichna/alchemists/alchemists)
==3552==  Address 0x541a2f8 is 8 bytes after a block of size 80 alloc'd
==3552==    at 0x4C2CD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3552==    by 0x4017F4: main (in /home/pmichna/alchemists/alchemists)
==3552== 
==3552== Invalid write of size 8
==3552==    at 0x4E3FA41: pthread_cond_init@@GLIBC_2.3.2 (pthread_cond_init.c:40)
==3552==    by 0x4018AA: main (in /home/pmichna/alchemists/alchemists)
==3552==  Address 0x541a2f0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 80 alloc'd
==3552==    at 0x4C2CD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3552==    by 0x4017F4: main (in /home/pmichna/alchemists/alchemists)
==3552== 
==3552== Invalid write of size 4
==3552==    at 0x4E3FA57: pthread_cond_init@@GLIBC_2.3.2 (pthread_cond_init.c:42)
==3552==    by 0x4018AA: main (in /home/pmichna/alchemists/alchemists)
==3552==  Address 0x541a2fc is 12 bytes after a block of size 80 alloc'd
==3552==    at 0x4C2CD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3552==    by 0x4017F4: main (in /home/pmichna/alchemists/alchemists)
==3552== 
Creating 4 alchemists...
TESTING_ERROR #0
TESTING_ERROR #1
Alchemist #0 started
TESTING_ERROR #2
TESTING_ERROR #3
Alchemist #1 started
Alchemist #1 going to think 4 seconds...
Alchemist #2 started
Alchemist #2 going to think 1 seconds...
Alchemist #3 started
```

Does it mean I use the `pthread_cond_init` function not correctly? How would I fix this?

Comment: That's a lot of code.  Have you tried running it with Valgrind?

Comment: @DietrichEpp No I haven't - I have heard about it but I haven't used it. However, you can see where it fails. It manages to write "TESTING ERROR #0". That's in the `main` function in the loop just before creating the first thread.

Comment: Well, then try running it with Valgrind.

Comment: Step through it using a debugger.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I added some Valgrind output. Still, it doesn't help me much.

Comment: @pmichna, you'd first have to compile it with debug options (`-g` would do) such that valgrind may trace errors back to the original source line.

Comment: fix those invalid reads and writes, they are very likely the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `pthread_cond_init` on elements of `pots_cond`:

```
pthread_cond_init(&pots_cond[i], NULL);
```

But the size used when allocating `pots_cond` was the size of `pthread_mutex_t` (as opposed to `pthread_cond_t`):

```
pots_cond = malloc(num_of_pots*sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
```

On my OS X system `sizeof(pthread_cond_t)` is 48, but `sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)` is 64, so this won't cause a problem (as you're actually allocating more memory than you need.)

However, when I fired up an Ubuntu Linux VM to check, it turns out `sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)` is only 40, in which case your code allocates *less* memory than you need and you will overrun `pots_cond`.

Comment: I knew it would be a problem like this... Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is why Valgrind is awesome. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
pots_cond = malloc(num_of_pots*sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
```

You're allocating this with a size of `pthread_mutex_t`. But you want a `pthread_cond_t`. Always do malloc on this form:

```
  pots_cond = malloc(num_of_pots*sizeof *pots_cond);
```

The comment here is also lying:

```
/* Wait for all threads to complete */ 
for (i = 0; i < num_of_alchemists; i++)
{
     pthread_join(threads_alchemists[i], NULL);
}
```

You only wait for `threads_alchemists`, not all your `&threads_apprentices`. When all the alchemists are done, you will continue to free() variables that the apprentice threads are using.

Answer (score 1):

casting integers to `void*` and then back as arguments to the thread functions is fundamentally wrong. If you are on a machine where `long` and `void*` have different width, you can end up with wrong things in the upper half of a word.

Use a table of `long[something]` instead and pass each thread the address of such a table entry.

Comment: This is bad advice because it makes the code more complicated, when you could just use `intptr_t` instead of `long`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp we obviously disagree on that one. Code becomes complicated if you violate interfaces and when you use useless casts. Calling this "bad advice" is certainly a bit strong, I could just take yours for that. Taking the habit of gratuitously casting integers around through `void*` is just that, a bad habit, and I don't think that this good advice on a site like SO.

Comment: Any time you allocate memory that is shared between threads you have to consider the lifetime of that memory, and the responsibility of disposing of that memory with respect to the lifetime of the thread which uses that memory.  Whereas if you use a cast there is no need to share memory at all.  Taking the habit of gratuitously creating new shared objects and passing them between threads is just that, a bad habit, and I don't think this good advice on a site like SO.

Comment: Or let me rephrase it: any time you cast something you risk making an error, and every time you use shared memory you risk making an error.  I consider the risks of using shared memory much higher than the risks of casting, so in this case I would prefer the casts.  It has nothing to do with habits.